# How to add Select Table to the response?

Tags: discord.py, nextcord

How can I add a select option to the bot's response so when I select one, it edits the message with another content?

[image: Stuff like this. Yes, it is from Dank Memer bot.]

Please help me. I do not have a example code just to add this to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those select menus or dropdowns are available in [discord.py 2.0](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)

#### Example

```py
import discord
from discord import commands, ui

class Dropdown(ui.Select):
    def __init__(self):
        # The options which can be chosen inside the dropdown
        options = [
            discord.SelectOption(label="Moderation", description="Shows all moderation commands", emoji=""),
            discord.SelectOption(label="Config", description="Shows all config commands", emoji="⚙️"),
            discord.SelectOption(label="Games", description="Shows all meme commands", emoji="")
        ]

        # placeholder: Will be shown when no option is chosen
        # options: The dropdown options which can be chosen
        # min_values, max_values: Indicates that only one of the three options can be picked
        super().__init__(placeholder="Choose a section", options=options, min_values=1, max_values=1)

    async def callback(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        # This function is called when the user has chosen an option
        # With the interaction parameter, you can send a response message.
        # With self.values you get a list of the user's selected options. We only want the first one.
        await interaction.response.send_message(f"You've chosen {self.values[0]}")


@bot.command()
async def dropdown(ctx: commands.Context):
    # Create a view
    view = ui.View()
    # Add the dropdown to this view
    view.add_item(Dropdown())

    # Send a message containing the view
    await ctx.send(f"**Dropdown**", view=view)
```

If you want to disable the `ui.Select` you can do that with the `disabled` kwarg. See more in the docs.

---

##### References:

- [`ui.Select`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/interactions/api.html?highlight=selectmenu#discord.ui.Select)
- [`ui.View`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/interactions/api.html?highlight=selectmenu#discord.ui.View)
- [`discord.SelectOption`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/interactions/api.html?highlight=selectmenu#discord.SelectOption)
- [`discord.Interaction`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/interactions/api.html?highlight=discord%20interaction#discord.Interaction)